# Отображение фона на планшете

Tags: html, css

Для iPad в вертикальной ориентации сжимается фон (исходное изображение - https://prnt.sc/g1dlub), браузер chrome. Для всех остальных устройств все отлично отображается. Добавила стили, но не помогает:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: cover;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что по вашему значит сжимается? Как именно сжимается? Что по вашему значит "отлично"? Какой браузер?

Comment: @Cheg извиняюсь, не указала.  Изображение выглядит (исходное) так https://prnt.sc/g1dlub. Браузер - Google Chrome

Comment: Это все нужно в вопросе указывать

Answer (score 1):

Chrome поддерживает данные правила css.

Попробуйте зайти браузером на сайт с помощью приватного просмотра, вероятно в нем просто сохранился в кеш ваш старый css.